# Help identify a component on a PSU

Tags: power-supply

[image: PSU Component]

Please help me identify a component on a PSU I saw on EEVblog.

What's the name of this component and what does it do? Thank you.

[Source: EEVblog #1036 - PSU Fire PCB Repair](https://youtu.be/VwdnGbI5ls8?list=PLTPd7w3pOwM3RFROu5FWVM03lc5_AGkee&t=1049)

Edit: The component in question is circled in red

Comment: Which, there are at least a dozen in that image.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was talking about the U shaped tube-like thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a shunt resistor (more specifically three in parallel) to measure high currents (likely for the current limiting mode). They are typically made to drop 75-100mV for the full range of current you want to measure.

Comment: Note how these shunt resistors are simply made by using some (probably) copper wire. You can also find this in many multimeters for the high current range like 10 A or 20 A. *Is that not inaccurate?* It might be but that can be *calibrated out* by applying a certain **known** current and measuring the resulting voltage. The microcontroller (elsewhere on that board) then only needs to "know" this error factor and can compensate for it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: they often look a bit different than copper, I would guess some alloy. In a lot of meters you find filings, a bit of solder, or traces of what looks like an attempt to cutting them. These are all ways to trim the actual resistor value in case digital compensation is too expensive...

Comment: I suspect they're not pure copper either. [Manganin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganin) is a good candidate.

Comment: Common materials are copper-nickel and copper-manganese or a mix of all three. They can be made quite accurately (1% or better) and in a PSU I doubt you will find a digital compensation for the OCP, but for the OCP a 1% resistor is plenty accurate.